# Create array/tensor of cycle shifted arrays

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, cycle

I want to create 2d tensor (or numpy array, doesn't really matter), where every row will be cycle shifted first row. I do it using `for` loop:

```
import torch
import numpy as np

a = np.random.rand(33, 11)
miss_size = 64
lp_order = a.shape[1] - 1
inv_a = -np.flip(a, axis=1)
mtx_size = miss_size+lp_order   # some constant
mtx_row = torch.cat((torch.from_numpy(inv_a), torch.zeros((a.shape[0], miss_size - 1 + a.shape[1]))), dim=1)
mtx_full = mtx_row.unsqueeze(1)
for i in range(mtx_size):
        mtx_row = torch.roll(mtx_row, 1, 1)
        mtx_full = torch.cat((mtx_full, mtx_row.unsqueeze(1)), dim=1)
```

unsqueezing is needed because I stack 2d tensors into 3d tensor

Is there more efficient way to do that? Maybe linear algebra trick or more pythonic approach.

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example?

Comment: @Ivan minimal example is in the text of post

Comment: Indeed, but please provide the `mtx_row`,  `miss_size`, and `lp_order` so it serves as a minimal example to show the desired behavior.

Comment: @Ivan added dummy constants

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `scipy.linalg.circulant()`:

```
scipy.linalg.circulant([1, 2, 3])
# array([[1, 3, 2],
#        [2, 1, 3],
#        [3, 2, 1]])
```

Comment: That's neat, but cycle will be still needed because of batch of such arrays. But thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can achieve this using [`torch.gather`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.gather.html) by constructing the appropriate index tensor. This approach works with batches too.

If we take this approach, the objective is to construct an index tensor where each value refers to an index in `mtx_row` (along the last dimension here `dim=1`). In this case, it would be shaped `(3, 3)`:

```
tensor([[0, 1, 2],
        [2, 0, 1],
        [1, 2, 0]])
```

You can achieve this by broadcasting `torch.arange` with its own transpose and applying modulo on the resulting matrix:

```
>>> idx = (n-torch.arange(n)[None].T + torch.arange(n)[None]) % n
tensor([[0, 1, 2],
        [2, 0, 1],
        [1, 2, 0]])
```

Let `mtx_row` be shaped `(2, 3)`:

```
>>> mtx_row
tensor([[0.3523, 0.0170, 0.1875],
        [0.2156, 0.7773, 0.4563]])
```

From there you need to `idx` and `mtx_row` so they have the same shapes:

```
>>> idx_ = idx[None].expand(len(mtx_row), -1, -1)
>>> val_ = mtx_row[:, None].expand(-1, n, -1)
```

Then we can apply `torch.gather` on the last dimension `dim=2`:

```
>>> val_.gather(-1, idx_)
tensor([[[0.3523, 0.0170, 0.1875],
         [0.1875, 0.3523, 0.0170],
         [0.0170, 0.1875, 0.3523]],

        [[0.2156, 0.7773, 0.4563],
         [0.4563, 0.2156, 0.7773],
         [0.7773, 0.4563, 0.2156]]])
```