# Is there a way to compute a circulant matrix in Pytorch?

Tags: pytorch

I want a similar function as in https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.circulant.html to create a circulant matrix using PyTorch. I need this as a part of my Deep Learning model (in order to reduce over-parametrization in some of my Fully Connected layers as suggested in https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.08448 (Fig.3))

The input of the function shall be a 1D torch tensor, and the output should be the 2D circulant matrix.

Comment: With how strides in tensors work, you can't construct a circulant matrix with a view (see [this discussion](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/making-a-circulant-matrix-from-a-given-vector-in-a-memory-efficient-way/20908)). However you *can* make a copy, see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69723873/create-array-tensor-of-cycle-shifted-arrays/69725153#69725153).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create array/tensor of cycle shifted arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69723873/create-array-tensor-of-cycle-shifted-arrays)

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `unfold` to extract sliding windows. But to get the correct order you need to flip (later unflip) the tensors, and first concatenate the flipped tensor to itself.

```
circ=lambda v:torch.cat([f:=v.flip(0),f[:-1]]).unfold(0,len(v),1).flip(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic function for pytorch tensors, to get the circulant matrix for one dimension. It's based on `unfold` and it works for 2d circulant matrix or high-dimension tensors.

```
def circulant(tensor, dim):
    """get a circulant version of the tensor along the {dim} dimension.
    
    The additional axis is appended as the last dimension.
    E.g. tensor=[0,1,2], dim=0 --> [[0,1,2],[2,0,1],[1,2,0]]"""
    S = tensor.shape[dim]
    tmp = torch.cat([tensor.flip((dim,)), torch.narrow(tensor.flip((dim,)), dim=dim, start=0, length=S-1)], dim=dim)
    return tmp.unfold(dim, S, 1).flip((-1,))
```

Essentially, this is a PyTorch version of [scipy.linalg.circulant](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.circulant.html) and works for multi-dimension tensors.

Also a similar question: [Create array/tensor of cycle shifted arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69723873/)

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-roll-some-rows-of-a-matrix/36722/2?u=yochanan_scharf)

```
n = len(vec)
arr = vec.repeat((n,1))
dim = 0 # all the rows
output = list(map(torch.roll, torch.unbind(arr, dim), tuple(range(n)))))
tensor_output = torch.stack(output)
```

Another method, [based on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57272600/3957794):

```
rolls = torch.arange(n)
vec[(torch.arange(n)[:,None]+rolls) % n]
```

The second method has been tested on 2d tensors.